# Google Translate Breaks Stylesheet in Firefox

Tags: firefox, stylesheet, google-translate

I am helping a client with an eCommerce site (runs on ProStores from eBay).

The issue is that the site's base stylesheet is breaking (being disabled) when the page is translated with the Google Translate widget. This only happens in Firefox. Chrome, IE(6-9), Opera and Safari are all fine.

Translate in FF was working prior to some changes we made recently: mostly graphical, some additions to the stylesheet. I had to tip-toe around their templates which were built with tables, outdated code etc. so I am overwhelmed when trying to troubleshoot this.

Here is a link to the site: http://www.myfantasticbags.com

(open in FF and use google translate in the header area to see the issue)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and much frustration with this.

The problem I was having was that it was translating my website's font-resizers - From 'large' to 'grande' etc. which was throwing off the font-resize element and entire site.

Try adding a **class="notranslate"** to any elements you think may be translating and throwing off your stylesheet.

Hope this helps!

Korey

Answer (score 1):

Add `class="skiptranslate"` to the head tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you also have a link to a print preview style sheet, so your visitors can see how pages will print, try this: Putting the link to your external stylesheet inside a div with class="notranslate", may not only fix the translation in Firefox but also when flipping back and forth between your print preview and default CSS in all browsers. I know that divs in the head tags are atypical, but I don't see any problem arise from that.